# Display product SKU on page with Jigoshop

Tags: e-commerce

I'm using the [Jigoshop plugin](http://jigoshop.com/) (everything's going great so far!) and need to display the product SKU on a page, does anyone know how to do this?

p.s I would ask on the Jigoshop forum but you have to pay for it.

Comment: Where in particular do you want it displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop-shop.php you can just add this:

```
SKU: <?php echo $_product->sku; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

What page do you need it on?  Depending on your theme, it does display on Single Product Pages and in 'certain' but not all emails.  This will happen if you have enabled SKU's in the Admin->Jigoshop->Settings->General Tab and set the option 'Enable SKU field' to Yes.  And of course, actually entering SKU's for each product as you create them.

Beyond that, there is no doubt that there are a few places that it doesn't display where it should (the rest of the emails, the Admin Order's display, the User's Account placed orders display) and I can say that there is an update for that and several other issues in the works, but can't say when that might be publicly ready.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. All my settings etc are turned on, the problem I'm having is placing the SKU where I want it. Is there a snippet of code for the SKU that I could just place anywhere on a page?